# Apache Spark Streaming from Azure Event Hubs with Databricks Error: Endpoint hostname cannot be null or empty

Tags: spark-streaming, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I am successfully streaming data to Azure Event Hub, howevever when I attempt to write the the stream using the code below, I get the following error:

```
Endpoint hostname cannot be null or empty
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 5b2fef8d-886a-411f-b39e-7b2540361cea, runId = 43b637e5-e1ca-47d0-b64e-b4a7af4c84e6]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {}

Current State: INITIALIZING
Thread State: RUNNABLE
logged message The streaming query failed to execute
Exception: Endpoint hostname cannot be null or empty
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 5b2fef8d-886a-411f-b39e-7b2540361cea, runId = 43b637e5-e1ca-47d0-b64e-b4a7af4c84e6]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {}

Current State: INITIALIZING
Thread State: RUNNABLE
```

The code that I'm using to write the streams is as follows:

```
streamingQuery = (
  df
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", f"{thelocation}/_checkpoints")
  .start(thelocation)
)
```

Any thoughts on resolving the issue?

I am passing Endpoint details as follows:

```
df_flight_data = flightdata_defn.build(withStreaming=True, options={'rowsPerSecond': 1})


streamingDelays = (
  df_flight_data
    .groupBy(
      #df_flight_data.body,
      df_flight_data.flightNumber,
      df_flight_data.airline,
      df_flight_data.original_departure,
      df_flight_data.delay_minutes,
      df_flight_data.delayed_departure,
      df_flight_data.reason,
      window(df_flight_data.original_departure, "1 hour")
    )
    .count()
)

writeConnectionString = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
checkpointLocation = "///checkpoint"

# ehWriteConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
# ehWriteConf = {
#   'eventhubs.connectionString' : writeConnectionString
# }

ehWriteConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : writeConnectionString
}



# Write body data from a DataFrame to EventHubs. Events are distributed across partitions using round-robin model.
ds = streamingDelays \
  .select(F.to_json(F.struct("*")).alias("body")) \
  .writeStream.format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehWriteConf) \
  .outputMode("complete") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "...") \
  .start()
```

Comment: How are you passing `Endpoint` details?

Comment: DKNY I have updated the question - hopefully that will answer your question

Comment: what is the value of `connectionString` ? (mask actual key...)